# gtkmm-2.4-dev for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gtkmm, fink

I'm trying to install gtkmm-2.4-dev for Mac OS X using fink.

`sudo fink install gtkmm-2.4-dev`

But I get the following response:

`Failed no package found for specification 'gtkmm-2.4-dev'!`

I know there is a fink package (according to http://www.gtkmm.org/en/download.html) for gtkmm-2.4-dev but I can't install it.

It seems to that the fink DB broke down: http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/pdb/package.php/gtkmm2.4-dev

Is there another way to install those libraries on a Mac?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
`sudo fink install gtkmm2.4-gtk-dev`

Comment: Consider accepting the answer, even if it's your own.